# Lookup and copy single column from one excel to another

Tags: vbscript

I have a script which copies the values of columns A and B to column A and B of another Excel. Column headers are same.
What I want is to lookup from first Excel value of Column A in the second Excel and if there is a match then get the value of corresponding
value of Column B in the same row and paste it in the first Excel. If there is no match, then insert #N/A in column B of first Excel.
There should be no change to second Excel(where we look up the value). Colummn B in the first Excel is empty.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST.xlsx")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\IPT\Test.xlsx")
'objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn
objWorkSheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Copy

Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

Set objRange = objWorkSheet2.Range("A:B")
objWorkSheet2.Paste objWorkSheet2.Range("A:B")
objWorksheet2.Paste(objRange)

objworkbook2.Save

objWorkbook.close("C:\TEST.xlsx")
objWorkbook2.close("C:\Desktop\IPT\Test.xlsx")

objExcel.Quit 
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Here is the first Excel

```
A   B   C
101     12
102     13
103     15
```

Second Excel File

```
A   B   C
101 Toy1    small
102 Toy2    medium
103 Toy3    high
```

Updated code:

```
ProcessFiles()
Sub ProcessFiles()

    Const xlUp = -4162
    Const vbCritical = 16

    Const BOOK1 = "C:\TEST.xlsx.xls"
    Const BOOK2 = "C:\Desktop\IPT\Test.xlsx"

    Dim xlApp, xlWB, dict, r
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FolderExists(BOOK1) Then
        MsgBox BOOK1 & " not found", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists(BOOK2) Then
        MsgBox BOOK2 & " not found", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(BOOK2)
    With xlWB.Worksheets(1)

        For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

            If Not dict.Exists(r.Text) Then dict.Add r.Text, r.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Next

    End With
    xlWB.Close False

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(BOOK1)
    With xlWB.Worksheets(1)

        For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

            'r.Offset(0, 4) = IIf(dict.Exists(r.Text), dict(r.Text), "#N/A")
            If dict.Exists(r.Text) Then
                r.Offset(0, 4) = dict(r.Text)
             Else
                r.Offset(0, 4) = "#N/A"
      End If

        Next

    End With
    xlWB.Close True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scripting Dictionaries make it easy to compare lists.

```
Sub ProcessFiles()

    Const xlUp = -4162
    Const vbCritical = 16

    Const BOOK1 = "\\norfile5\Public\Table Games\Spotlights\Back Up\SO\Book1.xlsx"
    Const BOOK2 = "\\norfile5\Public\Table Games\Spotlights\Back Up\SO\Book2.xlsx"

    Dim xlApp, xlWB, dict, r
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FolderExists(BOOK1) Then
        MsgBox BOOK1 & " not found", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists(BOOK2) Then
        MsgBox BOOK2 & " not found", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(BOOK2)
    With xlWB.Worksheets(1)

        For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

            If Not dict.Exists(r.Text) Then dict.Add r.Text, r.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Next

    End With

    xlWB.Close False

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(BOOK1)
    With xlWB.Worksheets(1)

        For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If dict.Exists(r.Text) then 
            r.Offset(0, 1) =  dict(r.Text)
        Else
            r.Offset(0, 1) =  "#N/A"
        End If

        Next

    End With

    xlWB.Save 

    xlWB.Close False

    xlApp.Quit

    Msgbox BOOK1 & " has been updated"
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting the following error while running the script:
1) Name redefined: 'vbCritical'
2) Type mismatch: 'Dir'
3) Type mismatch: 'IIF'

When I did some reseach on google, then the syntax looks ok to me for these but don't know why is it 
throwing error.

Comment: About Dir error, I found that 'Dir' function can't be used in vbscript

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code was throwing an error on Iff(vb script does not recognize Iff) so I updated it with a similar code below that line.
You can see it under updated code in my post. While I got your answer, I was able to modify your previous code
and got rid of errors. However, I am getting the following error now: 
'call was rejected by the callee'. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this.

1. Create a system to organize your data into arrays, then use several simple algorithms to slide things into place. This would require parsing cell by cell to retrieve the data.

I prefer this method as it has potential to be quite abstract as a program in itself. I also highly suggest using [arraylists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) if you do it.

2. Insert VLookup() functions into your Book1: Column B cells

I believe this would be more tedious...

Comment: @Mathew. May be I understand in theory but I am sorry I did not follow how to put this in code partly because my knowledge in VB script is quite limited. Can you please  codify.